# Is it fine to typecast from one implementation type to another while using an object?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns

I've a simple code base with few 'weapon' concrete classes which implements different contracts in order to be used by its clients.

My contracts:

```
public interface IWeaponPrimaryAttack
{
    void DoAttack();
}
public interface IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    void DoSecondaryAttack();
}
public interface IReloadable
{
    void Reload();
}
```

Concrete implementation or the actual weapons:

```
public class Katana : IWeaponPrimaryAttack, IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    public void DoAttack(){Console.WriteLine ("Swing");}
    public void DoSecondaryAttack() {Console.WriteLine ("Stab");}
}
public class ShotGun : IWeaponPrimaryAttack, IReloadable
{
    public void DoAttack(){Console.WriteLine ("Swing");}
    public void Reload() {//reload it}
}
```

Clients that uses these concrete classes:

```
public class PrimaryAttack
{
    private IWeaponPrimaryAttack _attack;
    public PrimaryAttack(IWeaponPrimaryAttack attack)
    {
        _attack = attack;
    }
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        _attack.DoAttack();
    }
}
public class SecondaryAttack
{
    private IWeaponSecondaryAttack _attack;
    public SecondaryAttack(IWeaponSecondaryAttack attack)
    {
        _attack = attack;
    }
    public void DoSecondaryAttack()
    {
        _attack.DoSecondaryAttack();
    }
}
public class WeaponReload
{
    private IReloadable _reloader;
    public WeaponReload(IReloadable reloader)
    {
        _reloader = reloader;
    }
    public void Reload()
    {
        _reloader.Reload();
    }
}
```

New of course the instantiation of concrete class only be known when the user selects one among many weapons(one among ShotGun, Katana, etc).

Let say the use has selected ShotGun as the weapon, based on the selection it might go like this:

```
IWeaponPrimaryAttack weapon = new ShotGun(); // get it from a factory
PrimaryAttack primaryAttack = new PrimaryAttack(weapon);
primaryAttack.DoAttack();
```

Now for the WeaponReload have to do a typecast here in order to use it.

```
WeaponReload reloader = new WeaponReload ((IReloadable)weapon);
reloader.Reload();
```

I have questions around it,

- Should I really have to end up typecasting eventually?
- Or there is a better way to handle this object creation part.
- Or there is entirely a better design that I can come up with which
  does not necessarily ends up in casting.
- Or casting it like this is totally fine.

Comment: use `enum` to define types like weapon type, attack type ..etc. Also, you need to concrete implementation of attack and weapon as both have different purpose and logic, so they need to be separate. Then, you can have a container which contains both like `WeaponAttack` to control the damage, timing ..etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first respond to your initial question:

### *is it fine to typecast from one implementation to another?*

**Absolutely!** When using *interfaces* to declare behaviours like you have shown, not only is it *fine* but it becomes important that you *DO* typecast, otherwise what was the point of declaring the behavior through interfaces in the first place.

The use of interfaces implies that not all classes will implement the behaviour, so you can *ONLY* access the behaviour if your code knows the exact type of the concrete class or if you know the *interface* of the behaviour you want to execute, perhaps more importantly you may need to handle the case where the concrete class *does NOT* implement the expected interface.

> *Should you have to Type Cast?*
>   If you are using interfaces, then yes you *should* have to typecast.

A better code implementation for *WeaponReload* would be to check first that the class does in fact implement `IReloadable` before reloading, since [c# 7.0 we can use the `is` operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator) to test an expression against a pattern and we can capture the output in a single line of code:

```cs
if (weapon is IReloadable reloader)
    reloader.Reload();
```

Notice we didn't even need to use the Wrapper *Client* class `WeaponReload` to access the `IReloadable.Reload()` behaviour, I think this is what you are referring to with:

### Is there a better way to handle this object creation part

Yes, the better way is to skip the *Clients* altogether.

If you are set on your current implementation, then that is just as easy to incorporate, however you should still handle the cases where the passed in object does not implement your interface.

```cs
WeaponReload reloader = null;
if (weapon is IReloadable r)
    reloader = new WeaponReload(r);
...
if (reloader != null)
    reloader.Reload();
```

### Is there an entirely better design that I can come up with which does not necessarily ends up in casting.

There is nothing wrong with casting, it can lead to clear and concise code as you have created clear structural boundaries that can help you separate implementation from definitions.

> If you are concerned about performance, then we have a solution for that too, **but don't optimise your code for the sake of it**, the performance losses due to boxing values into objects, though comparitively expensive to alternatives, wil not generally be noticied by the user unless you are performing millions of operations in quick succession.

To avoid performance issues caused by [*Boxing and Unboxing*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) in C# we can use [Generics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/). Interfaces play a huge part in C# generics, a generic type argument on a class or method defines *all* the interfaces or conditions that an `object` **MUST** implement for it to be passed into the methods as a parameter or stored in a variable.

Because these conditions are validated and enforced by the compiler, the storage and referencing to the underlying object stored in a generic typed variable is a lot more efficient at runtime compared to simply *boxing* objects into an `object` typed variable.

### a Better design

Your interfaces are on the right track, interfaces allow your concrete classes to define explicit behaviors without having to incorporate those behaviours into their base class.

What you have missed here is a base class that all your weapons can inherit from, it's the first logical assumption that one makes when rationalising a domain that includes different types of weapons like shotguns and swords... Common properties might include Name, Description, Cost, BasePower... I would argue that *all* weapons have a *Primary* attack function, so really a `Weapon` base class would be replacing `IWeaponPrimaryAttack`:

```cs
public abstract class Weapon ()
{
    public string Name { get;set; }
    ... 
    public abstract void DoAttack();
}
public interface IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    void DoSecondaryAttack();
}
public interface IReloadable
{
    void Reload();
}
```

Now for the concrete class implementations, I would classify the weapons a bit differently again, I like to write down a breif story style description about the classes before I write the code, using the following phrasiology to help validate that my classes and interfaces make sense and can be utilised effectivly:

> A `Katana` *IS* a `Weapon`, it has a Name of 'Katana' but it does *NOT* have a `Reload` feature, it's primary attack is a 'Slash' and it has a `SecondaryAttack` that is a 'Stab'.
>
> A `Shotgun` *IS* a `Weapon`, it has a Name of 'Shotgun' and it *DOES* have a `Reload` feature, it only has a capacity of `2` *shells* before it must be reloaded, it does not have a `SecondaryAttack`.

This will work with your current interfaces, but notice already we have identified an element of redundancy, the `Name` is always the same as the `type`. This isn't a problem, but it is an indicator that there is potential room for improvement. Instead lets create classes that categorise the weapons :

> In real life and in many games, you will find weapons categorised more granularly, for instance Swords vs Guns, Two handed vs One Handed, or Melee vs Ranged... Swords might include daggers and daggers can easily be Ranged as well as Melee...

Instead if we change our concrete classes to this:

```cs
public class Sword : Weapon, IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    public override void DoAttack() => Console.WriteLine("Slash");
    public void DoSecondaryAttack() => Console.WriteLine("Stab");
}
public class Gun : Weapon, IReloadable
{
    public override void DoAttack() => Console.WriteLine("Shoot");
    public void Reload() => Console.WriteLine("Reload");
}
```

We haven't yet handled the capacity of attacks before reload, should be easy to add this into the `IReloadable` interface, so we'll leave this out for.

Now we can create an array of weapons that the user might have access to that includes a 'Katana' as an *instance* of a 'Sword' as well as a 'Dagger' and of course our 'Shotgun' as an instance of `Gun`:

> even though 'Dagger' and 'Katana' have a similar attack style, one would clearly deal more damage than the other, so Damage now becomes another property that we could add...

```cs
List<Weapon> weapons = new List<Weapon>
                           {
                               new Sword { Name = "Katana" },
                               new Sword { Name = "Dagger" },
                               new Gun { Name = "Shotgun" }
                           };
```

Although it doesn't make sense in a real-world situation to talk about the *reload* function on a *Katana*, you could for the purposes of simplifying the code say that *all* `Weapon` instances do have a `Reload` function, but the `Reload` function on a *Katana* does nothing. The same could be said for SecondaryAttack, in that case these become properties on the `Weapon` base class. The argument about if it should or shouldn't be an interface could swing either way depending on how you implement it in the rest of your code.

Another scenario to consider is *What is an Attack*? By making the attack method a `void` response type, we're really saying that anything and everything could occur when the method is executed, we have not feedback and cannot determine if the attack succeeded, or if it even ocurred at all.

If Attack returned a value or better yet an object that defined the parameters of the attack, then we can start to tell some interesting stories! Take

> On the *third* attack, user with *Shotgun* equipped was out of ammo and had to use it as a 'blunt force' *melee* weapon, that had less damage, but required the user to be within melee range...

Write out user stories that explain the values and states of the objects over time, this will help you to identify the structures that you need, then we can talk about better implementations ;)

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. Now I think I have a better understand the of the idea. Though I have one thing in my mind. Let's consider that a Baseball Bat or a Hockey stick can be used as a weapon, but it's not really a weapon. So just to fit into real world can I just use an `interface` instead of an `abstract` class and have behavior like `DoAttack` . I'm not sure is this really mane any difference. Just asking if the way I'm looking into objects are right.

Comment: You could, if you really wanted to, but it's far more efficient and simpler to understand the code if you can constrain your classes to simpler concepts than what might be in real life. If _any_ object could have _any_ behaviour, then the reasoning behind your class design becomes ambiguous and your vision can become diluted over time or if you have to work in a team. So while you _can_, that doesn't mean you _should_, or that it is a good idea to do so. This is where the answer from @Cid and looking at Composition, over inheritance is a good place to start

Comment: A different design then might be for a `BaseballBat` (and all weapons) to inherit from `GameObject` that has an _array_ of abilities, then _instead_ of interfaces, (or as well as) use an Enum as a type discriminator on the ability, 'Melee, Ranged, ???'. Baseball bat has ['two hand swing' (Melee), 'one hand swing' (Melee), 'block' (Melee and Ranged defence) and throw (Ranged)] abilities. You can play baseball with these abilities, you can also fight with them, or use them to break other 'things'.

Comment: Have a clear understanding of what the finite list of objects are, how they might each independently vary and how they will interact with each other. Then look for the right balance of code constructs to help you achieve your aims. Don't try and cater for too many unknowns, put constraints on those unknowns to keep them and your code base manageable

Answer (score 2):

[Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

I would, instead of having differents weapons implementing differents interfaces defining their behaviour, create classes that holds the logic of the behaviour

Let's consider a weapon **can** have a primary attack, a secondary one and reload.

The class could be defined as such :

```
abstract class Weapon
{
    public IWeaponPrimaryAttack WeaponPrimaryAttack { get; set; }
    public IWeaponSecondaryAttack WeaponSecondaryAttack { get; set; }
    public IReloadable Reloadable { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we can define classes that holds differents behaviours of the interfaces.

In example :

```
public class SlashAttack : IWeaponPrimaryAttack
{
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performing a slash attack");
    }
}

public class StabAttack : IWeaponSecondaryAttack
{
    public void DoSecondaryAttack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performing a stab attack");
    }
}

public class Shooting12Caliber : IWeaponPrimaryAttack
{
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bam !");
    }
}

public class Caliber12Reloader : IReloadable
{
    public void Reload()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reloading caliber 12 !");
    }
}

public class ShootingWith556 : IWeaponPrimaryAttack
{
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bam (version 5.56) !");
    }
}

public class Caliber556Reloader : IReloadable
{
    public void Reload()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Reloading caliber 5.56 !");
    }
}
```

And now, you can use theses class as properties in differents weapon classes.

You'll implement once the methods and can use the same for differents weapons :

```
public class Katana : Weapon
{
    public Katana()
    {
         WeaponPrimaryAttack = new SlashAttack();
         WeaponSecondaryAttack = new StabAttack();
    }
}

public class Machete : Weapon
{
    public Machete()
    {
         WeaponPrimaryAttack = new SlashAttack();
    }
}

public class Shotgun : Weapon
{
    public Shotgun()
    {
         WeaponPrimaryAttack = new Shooting12Caliber();
         Reloadable = new Caliber12Reloader();
    }
}

public class AssaultRifleWithBayonet : Weapon
{
    public AssaultRifleWithBayonet()
    {
         WeaponPrimaryAttack = new ShootingWith556();
         WeaponSecondaryAttack = new StabAttack();
         Reloadable = new Caliber556Reloader();
    }
}
```

Now, your methods implementations are refactored within classes and are reusable. You don't need to typecast to check if this or that interface is implemented.

```
if (weapon.Reloadable != null)
{
    weapon.Reloadable.Reload();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("This weapon isn't meant to be reloaded");
}

/*
This works too if you want to omit the Reloadable != null

public class CannotReload : IReloadable
{
    public void Reload()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This weapon isn't meant to be reloaded");
    }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Weapon` and `Attack` are partially related, you may need to implement each separately in order to make them flexible for future changes, and since `Attack` can be defined in multiple classes (not just for weapons), we can either implement an interface for it, or an abstract class, (or both if needed) and use it as `definition` of the attack logic.

If you want to define a concrete class for each weapon, and just inherit the `Weapon` class, you can do that, though, it won't be easy to handle nor to memorized; because more weapons, means more classes to handle.

For your current code, you could start with something like these interfaces :

```
public interface IWeapon
{
    WeaponType Type {  get; set;  }
}

public interface IReloadable 
{
    double IsReloadable {  get; set;  }     
    void Reload();    
}

public interface IAttack
{
    AttackType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using `enum` to define some types :

```
public enum WeaponType { Katana, Shutgun, Knife }
public enum AttackType { Primary, Secondary }
```

now, we will use them in our classes

```
public class Weapon : IWeapon, IReloadable
{
    public WeaponType Type { get; set; }

    public bool IsReloadable  { get; set; } 

    public void Reload()
    {
        if(IsReloadable)
        {
            .....
        }
    }
    ...
}

public class Attack : IAttack
{
    public AttackType Type { get; set; }    
    ....    
}

public class WeaponAttack
{
    private readonly Weapon _weapon; 

    private readonly Attack _attack;

    public WeaponAttack(Weapon weapon, Attack attack)
    {
        _weapon = weapon; 
        _attack = attack;
    }

    public void DoAttack()
    {
        if(_attack.Type == AttackType.Primary)
        {
            // do something..
        }       
    }   

}
```

With this, we know if we use `Weapon` or `Attack` we are defining types, and setting their properties, logic for each type to be ready for use. `WeaponAttack` will use these `prepared` objects to do some actions on them.

so in your example of shutgun, we'll be revised to this

```
//define your weapon
var shutgun = new Weapon
{
        Type = WeaponType.Shutgun, 
        IsReloadable = true 
};
//define your attack 
var attack = new Attack
{
    Type = AttackType.Primary, 
    DamagePoints = 2.5
}; 

// take the action 
var attackAction = new WeaponAttack(shutgun, attack); 
attackAction.DoAttack();
```

This is the simplest form that came to my mind. It'll be easy to extend, for instance, say you want to add a new interface `IDamage` for storing damage points per attack :

```
public interface IDamage
{
    double DamagePoints { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you just implement it on `Attack` class :

```
public class Attack : IAttack, IDamage
{
    public AttackType Type { get; set; }    

    public double DamagePoints { get; set; }
}
```

Same thing applies to the Weapon class, if you want to add new features, it would be easy to add with minimal modifications to the current code. Also, I would prefer to change the constructor on `WeaponAttack` to accept the interfaces instead of the concrete class, it would be more fixable this way. But I used the concrete classes just for demonstration purpose.